# How to run HttpWatch concurrently in multiple browser windows with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, httpwatch

We want to execute a selenium script concurrently in multiple browser windows and capture the request timings with HttpWatch. When we try that we get the error:

*com4j.ComException: 80004005 Unspecified error : AttachByTitle failed because more than one IE or Chrome page was found with the title 'Signin' - AttachByTitle failed : .\invoke.cpp:517*

Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that HttpWatch is attempting to attach by the title of the browser window but you have multiple windows with the same title.

Please set the title of each of the browser windows to something unique before you attach HttpWatch. This page in the documentation shows how to set the title to a unique GUID with Selenium before calling AttachByTitle:

https://apihelp.httpwatch.com/HttpWatch_API~HttpWatch.Controller~AttachByTitle.html